# How to show a label in app on Apple Watch

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, watchkit

I've changed a label in iOS app via an api. It changed successfully. Now I want to show this label value in Apple Watch Label.
I tried doing it by `InterfaceController *ic;` and doing it's `alloc` & `init` and then where my api get success I'm doing `ic.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempDict objectForKey:@"summary"]];`
 So it is not working. Any clues?

Comment: Where are you attempting to change the label? In your WatchKit extension? You can't do it directly from the iOS app.

Comment: yes exactly. Then how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can request data from iOS app.
Need to implement this method in Watch App:

```
[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:@{@"KEY":@"getValue"}
                                       reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
                                      [self updateLabelWithString:replyInfo(@"value")];
                                       }];
```

And in iOS app AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)applicationhandleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
          reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
{
reply(@{@"value":@"your data"});
}
```

The app delegate performs the request using the provided dictionary and then returns a reply to the WatchKit extension.

Comment: You could also look into using Darwin notifications to notify the WatchKit app right away, if it's currently running. Check out MMWormhole to make this easier: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole

Comment: @bgilham Seems great. Let me give it a try.